# How to focus the first control from the TableLayoutPanel on new button click

Tags: c#, winforms

I have inherited the new save close buttons from base form to all the forms. I write the code in the base form to clear all the controls when new button clicked.

```
foreach (Control ctrl in cc)
{
    if (ctrl.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
        ctrl.Text = "";

    else if (ctrl.GetType() == typeof(ComboBox))
    {
        ComboBox cb = ctrl as ComboBox;
        cb.SelectedIndex = -1;
        cb.Text = "";
    }
}
```

This code will clear all the TextBoxes and ComboBoxes. Now I want to focus the first TextBox after clicking the new button. Code must write in base form to focus first control in all the inherited forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may get the first `TextBox` from the Control Collection on the base form using LINQ FirstOrDefault. Later you can call its [Focus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.focus.aspx) method.

```
TextBox firstTextBox = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().FirstOrDefault();
if(firstTextBox != null)
    firstTextBox.Focus();
```

Comment: put a break point and see if you are getting a TextBox in `firstTextBox`

Comment: Iam getting firstTextBox value null

Comment: Sir my textboxes are on the table layout panel. Thats why iam getting null. If i remove the tablelayout panel, Iam getting textbox value. But i want my controls on tablelayoutpanel only

Comment: okkk, do you have the tablelayoutpanel on your base forms ? if so then replace `this.Controls` with your `tablelayout.Controls`, where `tablelayout` is the ID of your Table Lay out panel.

Comment: still Iam not able to focus sir. because baseform table layout panel name is different to child form tablelayout panel name.

Comment: In your code in question, what is `CC`, can you access the TextBox through that ?

Comment: then try with `cc.Controls`